# Sort awt Rectangle by Surface Area using Comparable

Tags: sorting, comparable

This code compares `awt` rectangles by surface area but I am getting an error when I use `collections.sort`. I want it to output a sorted `ArrayList` of `awt` rectangles based on their surface area.

`surface area = width * height.`

I have created a sorting class and extended the `comparable` interface and I am calling/invoking this class as a parameter in   `Collections.sort(rectangleList, new SortBySurfaceArea());`, however when I put a cursor over `collections.sort`, I get this pop-up error.

```
no suitable method found for sort(List<Rectangle>,SortBySurfaceArea)
    method Collections.<T#1>sort(List<T#1>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#1
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
    method Collections.<T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2
        (argument mismatch; SortBySurfaceArea cannot be converted to Comparator<? super T#2>))
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Comparable<? super T#1> declared in method <T#1>sort(List<T#1>)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2>sort(List<T#2>,Comparator<? super T#2>)

(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Code listing follows:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class RectangleSurfaceAreaComparable {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

        Rectangle rectangle_0 = new Rectangle(50, 4);
        Rectangle rectangle_1 = new Rectangle(80, 3);
        Rectangle rectangle_2 = new Rectangle(90, 2);

        System.out.println(surfaceArea(rectangle_0.getWidth(), rectangle_0.getHeight()));

        List<Rectangle> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();
        rectangleList.add(rectangle_0);
        rectangleList.add(rectangle_1);
        rectangleList.add(rectangle_2);

        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangleList) {
            System.out.println("" + rectangle);
        }
        Collections.sort(rectangleList, new SortBySurfaceArea());
        for (Rectangle rectangle : rectangleList) {
            System.out.println("" + rectangle);
        }

    }

    /**
     *
     * @param width
     * @param height
     * @return
     */
    public static double surfaceArea(double width, double height) {
        double sa = width * height;
        return sa;
    }

}
```

**SortBySurfaceArea.java**

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author HP
 */
public class SortBySurfaceArea implements Comparable<Rectangle> {

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Rectangle o) {
        return (o.height * o.width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Collections.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) needs a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), not a [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), so your `SortBySurfaceArea` could be:

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class SortBySurfaceArea implements Comparator<Rectangle>
{
    public int compare(Rectangle o1, Rectangle o2)
    { return o1.height*o1.width-o2.height*o2.width; }
}
```

> No I want to use comparable

How about this? (You might want to call `SortBySurfaceArea` differently, e. g.  `SortableRectangle`.)

```
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class SortBySurfaceArea extends Rectangle implements Comparable<Rectangle>
{
    public SortBySurfaceArea(Rectangle r) { super(r); }
    public int compareTo(Rectangle o) { return height*width-o.height*o.width; }
}
```

```
…
        List<SortBySurfaceArea> rectangleList = new ArrayList<>();
        rectangleList.add(new SortBySurfaceArea(rectangle_0));
        rectangleList.add(new SortBySurfaceArea(rectangle_1));
        rectangleList.add(new SortBySurfaceArea(rectangle_2));
…
        Collections.sort(rectangleList);
```

Comment: No I want to use comparable

Comment: So you don't want to use `Collections.sort`?

Comment: it's okay. get rid of collection.sort

Comment: Or we keep it in its simplest form.

Comment: Get rid of collection.sort